Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS not waking up after sleep
Recently reinstalled ubuntu to my PC and its not waking up second time after sleeping (sleep successful wake up second sleep now cant wake up). So I can wake up once but the second time there is no signal to the display and to the keyboard.
I tried updating grub and nvidia drivers which didn't help. I have the output of journalctl -r | grep suspend
Sep 18 11:29:05 uhur-desktop kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Sep 18 11:29:05 uhur-desktop systemd-sleep[6543]: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
Sep 18 11:29:05 uhur-desktop systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
                                                suspend@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/loginManager.js:199:21
Sep 18 11:28:35 uhur-desktop ModemManager[1646]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Sep 18 11:28:35 uhur-desktop systemd-logind[1519]: The system will suspend now!
Sep 18 11:27:33 uhur-desktop logger[5633]: <13>Sep 18 11:27:33 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Sep 18 11:27:33 uhur-desktop suspend[5633]: nvidia-resume.service
Sep 18 11:27:33 uhur-desktop systemd-logind[1519]: Operation 'suspend' finished.
Sep 18 11:27:33 uhur-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend.target - Suspend.
Sep 18 11:27:33 uhur-desktop systemd[1]: Reached target suspend.target - Suspend.
Sep 18 11:27:33 uhur-desktop systemd[1]: Finished systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend.
Sep 18 11:27:33 uhur-desktop systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 18 11:27:33 uhur-desktop systemd-sleep[5405]: System returned from sleep operation 'suspend'.
Sep 18 11:27:33 uhur-desktop kernel: PM: suspend exit
Sep 18 11:27:33 uhur-desktop kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Sep 18 11:27:26 uhur-desktop kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Sep 18 11:27:26 uhur-desktop systemd-sleep[5405]: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
Sep 18 11:27:26 uhur-desktop systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Sep 18 11:27:24 uhur-desktop ModemManager[1646]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Sep 18 11:27:24 uhur-desktop systemd-logind[1519]: The system will suspend now!


Can you help me with this?

I get the same issue with Ubuntu 24.04, kernel 6.8.0-45 - apparently you need to update to kernel 6.10.3
https://forum.linuxconfig.org/t/suspend-bug-for-ubuntu-24-04lts/7853/9
